# Copy/Paste function within ForEach loop doesn't do anything VBA

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

Previously I was having issues with the lrSource variable not referencing the correct worksheet, but I added code to fix this issue. Before I corrected the issue, the code would paste some data into "MASTER.xlsx" but not the correct portions due to the lrSource variable not getting the correct last row. Now, I can get the correct last row and I don't receive any errors, but no data is copied to the file destination ("MASTER.xlsx")...Any suggestions?

```
Sub btnUpdateSAPData_Click()
'Declaring and Setting Variables
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Dim MyDir As String
Dim fil As Scripting.file
Dim FolderSource As Scripting.Folder
Dim FolderPathDest As String, wbDest As Workbook, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
Dim lrDest As Long, fileDest As String, lrSource As Long
Dim CurrentFile As String
Dim fileSource As String

MyDir = "C:\Users\quirk\Desktop\Cory Project\Wave 1A Content\SAPCL Spreadsheets\July 2018"

'Defining destination characteristics
FolderPathDest = "C:\Users\quirk\Desktop\Cory Project\VBA Code\Master FOlder"
fileDest = "C:\Users\quirk\Desktop\Cory Project\VBA Code\Master FOlder\MASTER.xlsx"
'Workbooks.Open Filename:=fileDest
Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook ' Workbooks("MASTER.xlsx")
Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("Sheet1")


'Looping through files
Set FolderSource = fso.GetFolder(MyDir)
For Each fil In FolderSource.Files
    Debug.Print fil.Name
    CurrentFile = fil.Name
    If Not fso.FileExists(FolderPathDest & "\" & fil.Name) Then
        fso.CopyFile _
        Source:=MyDir & "\" & fil.Name _
        , Destination:=FolderPathDest & "\" & fil.Name
            fileSource = MyDir & "\" & fil.Name
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=fileSource '
            ActiveWindow.Visible = False
            Set wbSource = Workbooks(CurrentFile)
            Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
                lrSource = wsSource.Range("A" & wsSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                lrDest = wsDest.Range("A" & wsDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Range("A2:V" & lrSource).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Range("A" & lrDest)
    End If
Next fil

End Sub
```

Comment: Within your loop, I don't see where you open the current file, so it will not be in the `Workbooks` collection, and you won't be able to refer to any `Worksheet` or `Range` within it.

Comment: @BigBen I just realized that a few minutes ago...I updated my code with that change but now even when I run my code, no errors pop up, but no data is copied and pasted into "MASTER.xlsx". I just updated the code on this post...do you see where I could be going wrong?

Comment: `wsSource.Range("A2:V"...` maybe?

Comment: Use some `Debug.Print` statements prior to the copy/paste. Make sure to print out the `Debug.Print lsSource.Address` and potentially other useful values to ensure the ranges are covering the correct data.

Comment: you want to open the workbook right before this assignment, Activeworkbook is unpredictable but not if you use right after the open: Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook

Comment: also make this wsSource.Range("A2:V" & lrSource).Copy, you can't only sometimes explicitly refer to to the workbooks or worksheets, you do it on this line for one but not the other

Comment: Change lrSource and lrDest to wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) and wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) if your last rows are not working out propoerly.

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code I ended up creating a whole different Workbook and copying and pasting my code into the new buttons I have the subroutines connected to and now the code works...not really sure what was going on.

Comment: Interesting. . . .